# How to use select with GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the task. 
"For each order, enter the total number of units ordered and the customer's name."
Database: Microsoft SQL Server 12.0.2000.8
I write that code so far:

```
    SELECT a.OrderID, SUM(a.Quantity), c.CompanyName FROM [Order Details] as a 
INNER JOIN Orders as b ON b.OrderID = a.OrderID
INNER JOIN Customers as c ON c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID

GROUP BY a.OrderID
```

But i can not display CompanyName. It should be only one Company Name for each order and we do not need to concat it. How can i do that? 
I enclose my database diagram. 
[image]

Comment: Do you get an error when you run the code? What's the specific error? As a hint, when you use `GROUP BY` the columns that you return must either be in the `GROUP BY` or be aggregate functions. Do you need the OrderByID? Do you actually just want the Quantity or do you want to do something with it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I wrote SUM(a.Quantity). I want to get rows with all OrdersID with sum of their Quantity, and Name of Company which have that OrderID

Comment: You need to add the company column to your group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're probably getting is that all non-aggregated columns should be present in the `GROUP BY` clause.

So the mistake is basically in the missing `CompanyName` column in the `GROUP BY`.

The query should, thus, look like this:

```
SELECT
    a.OrderID,
    SUM(a.Quantity) as TotalQuantity,
    c.CompanyName
FROM [Order Details] as a 
INNER JOIN Orders as b ON b.OrderID = a.OrderID
INNER JOIN Customers as c ON c.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
GROUP BY a.OrderID, c.CompanyName
```

[Works](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56151/1/0)